# Logic check. Octave

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I am getting different results between the below iterative way and a simple vector way in octave(simple regression). What am I doing wrong in the iterative way ?

1. Iterative version

   ```
   sum_val = 0;

   for m_val = 1:m,
       h = X(m_val,:) * theta;
       err_sq = power((h - y(m_val)),2);
       sum_val = sum_val + err_sq;
   end;

   J = (1/2*m)*sum_val;
   ```
2. Vector way:

   ```
   J = (1/(2*m))*sum(power((X*theta - y),2));
   ```

Comment: Some dimensions would be helpful, particularly of `X` and `theta`. Better yet would be example inputs and outputs for both methods showing the differences in the results.

Comment: Are you sure that `(1/2*m)` and `(1/(2*m))` are producing the same value? Why have you done this differently in each method?

Comment: As an aside `power((h - y(m_val)),2)` is surely not as good as `(h - y(m_val))^2` in terms of readability

Comment: See: [`PEMDAS`](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MATLAB, and so I presume in Octave as well, `1/2*m` is not the same as `1/(2*m)`. This is your source of error.

Comment: @excaza I don't agree with that. It is the language that defines the scope of the `/` operator. When we write a fraction by hand we have the advantage of writing over multiple lines and so that scope is clear. But an inline operator is ambiguous.